# Let $M$ be invertible, orthogonal, antisymmetric. Suppose $X$ belongs to $L_M$. Show that there is a symmetric $S$ with $X=MS$. (3 other variants).

Tags: linear-algebra

1. $M^T = M$ and $X\in J_M(K)$, then there exists a symmetric matrix S with
   $X = MS$.
2. If $M^T = M$ and $X \in L_M(K)$, then there exists an anti- symmetric matrix
   $S$ with $X = MS$.
3. If $M^T = -M$ and $X \in J_M(K)$, then there exists an anti-symmetric matrix
   $S$ with $X = MS$.
4. If $M^T = -M$ and $X\in L_M(K)$, then there exists a symmetric matrix $S$
   with $X = MS$.

Attempt:

1.

2. 
3. So let $M^T=M^{-1}$ and $M^T=M$. Let $X\in J_M(K)$. So $X=M^{-1}X^TM$. Equivalently, $MX=X^TM$. If at all there exists an $X$, with $X=MS$, then the only coice for $S$ has to be $S=M^{-1}X$. Now $S^T=(M^{-1}X)^T=X^T(M^{-1})^T=X^T(M^T)^T=X^TM=MX=M^TX=-MX$. So $S^T=-S$.
4. If $X=MS$ then $S$ necessarily is $M^{-1}X=M^TX$ because $M$ is orthogonal. Then $S=M^TX$ so $S^T=X^TM$. Now, $X\in L_M$ so $X^TM=-MX$ so $S^T=-MX=M^TX=S$ (because $M^T=M$). So $S^T=S$.